# Redirect loop after PHP update?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

I have a couple of PHP projects (one in Laravel 5.2, the other in CodeIgniter 2). After a security update to PHP on the server (both run on the same server), both applications now suffer from a redirect loop upon successful login. This, of course, causes the browser to croak and refuse to load the page. I have to close the browser window and open it incognito. At this point it'll go ahead and load the login page again.

Clearly, sessions and redirects are both a factor.

Has anyone seen a sudden redirect loop after a PHP update?

Here's some example code. The Laravel 5.2 app uses the boilerplate authentication code that comes baked into the framework (RedirectIfAuthenticated.php middleware):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

In the Codeigniter 2 app, I rolled my own authentication. (years ago. Bleh.)

```
redirect(base_url().'index.php/voucher/list_vouchers/'.$this->session->userdata('id'), 'refresh');
```

Comment: You should include the PHP version into your question.

Comment: Can you show your redirect code?

Comment: Probably the server cuts the Referer header of the HTTP requests.

Comment: I've added some example code. Apologies for forgetting that.